# Is there a way to load a YouTube iframe only after the contents have fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm developing a website for a YouTuber so of course have videos loaded onto the page. I'm calling the API using an external PHP script via AJAX that returns the title and ID of the video. These are then placed in the HTML. The code I currently have probably isn't the most efficient but I started out with only 1 video on the page so it was easier to just add to the code rather than redo it. This is the code I have (I don't feel it's necessary to include the PHP. It just returns JSON with the info for each video):

HTML:

```
<h3 id="video-title-1"></h3>

<!-- Video container -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div id="video-div0">
        <iframe id="video-embed-1" class="embed-responsive-item" 
                width="710" height="399" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     </div>
</div><!-- End video container -->

4 more of these, one for each video.
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getYTVideos() {

        var yTUrlPart = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getYTVideos.php', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) {
                $("#video-title-1").html(data.video0.title);
                $("#video-embed-1").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video0.id);

                $("#video-title-2").html(data.video1.title);
                $("#video-embed-2").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video1.id);

                $("#video-title-3").html(data.video2.title);
                $("#video-embed-3").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video2.id);

                $("#video-title-4").html(data.video3.title);
                $("#video-embed-4").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video3.id);

                $("#video-title-5").html(data.video4.title);
                $("#video-embed-5").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video4.id);

                // Hides the loading icon/text
                $(".social-loading-youtube").hide();
                // Displays the videos, which start out as display: none.
                $("#carousel-videos").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    };
```

Now, this all works fine but here's the problem. The loading icon gets hidden when the title and ID are inserted into the HTML, but obviously the actual video still has to load. So on a slow internet, when the loading icon disappears, the title appears but the video may not for a few seconds, leaving a big red space of nothing.

Heres a gif of what I mean to make it clearer: http://gfycat.com/DecentWigglyKillerwhale (Gifycat likes giving them very strange links. Also, sorry about the potato quality).

Basically, my question is... **Is there a way to keep the loading icon there until the video has completely loaded?**

Sorry about the long post. I appreciate any answers given, thanks,

Oli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like

```
var loadedIframes = 0, onIframeLoad;
onIframeLoad = function() {
  loadedIframes++;
  if (jQuery("iframe").size() === loadedIframes) { //Once all iframes are loaded, you show/hide loader and iframes
    // Hides the loading icon/text
    $(".social-loading-youtube").hide();
    // Displays the videos, which start out as display: none.
    $("#carousel-videos").css("display", "block");
  }
}
jQuery('iframe').on("load", onIframeLoad);
function getYTVideos() {

    var yTUrlPart = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getYTVideos.php', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {
            $("#video-title-1").html(data.video0.title);
            $("#video-embed-1").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video0.id);

            $("#video-title-2").html(data.video1.title);
            $("#video-embed-2").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video1.id);

            $("#video-title-3").html(data.video2.title);
            $("#video-embed-3").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video2.id);

            $("#video-title-4").html(data.video3.title);
            $("#video-embed-4").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video3.id);

            $("#video-title-5").html(data.video4.title);
            $("#video-embed-5").attr("src", yTUrlPart + data.video4.id);
        }
    });
};
getYTVideos();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should this go in a `$(document).ready(function {...});` or anything? Sorry, my JS skills aren't the best.

Comment: If you want, you can wrap everything with a function executed when DOM is ready (as you say, $(document).ready ...)

Comment: That's spot on! Thank you very much!